# Does hexdump respect the endianness of its system?

Tags: utilities, bsd, hexdump

On my machine I get the following output when I run these commands:

```
$ echo foos > myfile
$ hexdump myfile
6f66 736f 000a
```

The output from hexdump is little-endian. Does this mean that my machine is little-endian, or does hexdump always use little-endian format?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The traditional BSD `hexdump` utility uses the platform's endianness, so the output you see means your machine is little-endian.

Use `hexdump -C` (or `od -t x1`) to get consistent byte-by-byte output irrespective of the platform's endianness.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553493/how-to-print-only-the-hex-values-from-hexdump-without-the-line-numbers-or-the-as#15554717) for custom formats of `hexdump`'s output.

Answer (score 6):

From the manpage:

```
 -x      Two-byte hexadecimal display.  Display the input offset in hexa‐
         decimal, followed by eight, space separated, four column, zero-
         filled, two-byte quantities of input data, in hexadecimal, per
         line.
```

...

```
 If no format strings are specified, the default display is equivalent to
 specifying the -x option.
```

Your output is little-endian (least significant byte first), which is also the endianness of the x86 and x86_64 architectures, which you are probably using.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the man page not mention anywhere that it is treating the "two-byte quantities" as integers?  I thought I was taking crazy pills...

Comment: @slashingweapon "two-byte quantity of input data" _is_ `uint16_t` integer.

Comment: "Two bytes" is not the same as uint16_t on a little-endian system.

Comment: Furthermore, we should stop using this ambiguous term called "byte". If you meant 8-bit units, then "octet" would be precise.

Comment: That ship has sailed, @ZeZNiQ. At this point, "byte" and "octet" are synonyms, and only rather old reference materials refer to "bytes" of any other size...